# Read file from line 2 or skip header row

Tags: python, file-io

How can I skip the header row and start reading a file from line2?

Answer (score 583, accepted):

```
with open(fname) as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        #do something
```

Comment: if you need the header later, instead of `next(f)` use `f.readline()` and store it as a variable

Comment: Or use `header_line = next(f)`.

Comment: myone complains `'file' object is not an iterator` if I use `next(f)` approach. Instead the `f.readline()` worked.

Comment: @soMuchToLearnAndShare  Which python version did you use? It's better to provide information for reproducing the error.

Answer (score 110):

```
f = open(fname,'r')
lines = f.readlines()[1:]
f.close()
```

Comment: This will skip 1 line. `['a', 'b', 'c'][1:]` => `['b', 'c']`

Comment: @LjubisaLivac is right - this answer generalises to any line, so this is a much more powerful solution.

Comment: This is fine UNTIL the file is too large to read. This is fine for small files.

Comment: The slice also builds a *copy* of the contents. This is just unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: What about using `consume()` from `more-itertools` as stated in https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes ? I heard about this on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113803

Answer (score 30):

If you want the first line and then you want to perform some operation on file this code will helpful.

```
with open(filename , 'r') as f:
    first_line = f.readline()
    for line in f:
            # Perform some operations
```

Comment: It is not necessary to assign readline() to a variable if one does not need this line. I like this solution most, however.

Comment: Mixing direct reads with using the file as an iterator isn't recommended (although in this specific case no harm is done).

Answer (score 21):

If slicing could work on iterators...

```
from itertools import islice
with open(fname) as f:
    for line in islice(f, 1, None):
        pass
```

Comment: This is a really nice and pythonic way of solving the problem and can be extended to an arbitrary number of header lines

Comment: This is a really nice execution!

Comment: Marvellous solution

Comment: This should be upvoted much, much more than it currently is.

Comment: This solution is really good. This even works for in-memory uploaded file while iterating over file object.

Answer (score 9):

```
f = open(fname).readlines()
firstLine = f.pop(0) #removes the first line
for line in f:
    ...
```

Comment: This will read the entire file into memory at once, so it's only practical if you're reading a fairly small file.

Answer (score 2):

To generalize the task of reading multiple header lines and to improve readability I'd use method extraction. Suppose you wanted to tokenize the first three lines of `coordinates.txt` to use as header information.

**Example**

```
coordinates.txt
---------------
Name,Longitude,Latitude,Elevation, Comments
String, Decimal Deg., Decimal Deg., Meters, String
Euler's Town,7.58857,47.559537,0, "Blah"
Faneuil Hall,-71.054773,42.360217,0
Yellowstone National Park,-110.588455,44.427963,0
```

Then method extraction allows you to specify *what* you want to do with the header information (in this example we simply tokenize the header lines based on the comma and return it as a list but there's room to do much more).

```
def __readheader(filehandle, numberheaderlines=1):
    """Reads the specified number of lines and returns the comma-delimited 
    strings on each line as a list"""
    for _ in range(numberheaderlines):
        yield map(str.strip, filehandle.readline().strip().split(','))

with open('coordinates.txt', 'r') as rh:
    # Single header line
    #print next(__readheader(rh))

    # Multiple header lines
    for headerline in __readheader(rh, numberheaderlines=2):
        print headerline  # Or do other stuff with headerline tokens
```

**Output**

```
['Name', 'Longitude', 'Latitude', 'Elevation', 'Comments']
['String', 'Decimal Deg.', 'Decimal Deg.', 'Meters', 'String']
```

If `coordinates.txt` contains another headerline, simply change `numberheaderlines`. Best of all, it's clear what `__readheader(rh, numberheaderlines=2)` is doing and we avoid the ambiguity of having to figure out or comment on why author of the the accepted answer uses `next()` in his code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read multiple CSV files starting from line 2, this works like a charm

```
for files in csv_file_list:
        with open(files, 'r') as r: 
            next(r)                  #skip headers             
            rr = csv.reader(r)
            for row in rr:
                #do something
```

(this is part of [Parfait's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56295720/5675325) to a different question)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Open a connection to the file
with open('world_dev_ind.csv') as file:

    # Skip the column names
    file.readline()

    # Initialize an empty dictionary: counts_dict
    counts_dict = {}

    # Process only the first 1000 rows
    for j in range(0, 1000):

        # Split the current line into a list: line
        line = file.readline().split(',')

        # Get the value for the first column: first_col
        first_col = line[0]

        # If the column value is in the dict, increment its value
        if first_col in counts_dict.keys():
            counts_dict[first_col] += 1

        # Else, add to the dict and set value to 1
        else:
            counts_dict[first_col] = 1

# Print the resulting dictionary
print(counts_dict)
```