# Print specific line in a .txt file in Python?

Tags: python, printing, line

I have got a .txt file that contains a lot of lines. I would like my program to ask me what line I would like to print and then print it into the python shell. The .txt file is called packages.txt.

Comment: I tried: 'f=open('packages.txt')
         lines=f.readlines()'

Comment: sorry, i dont know how to format code...?

Comment: Code is best put into the *question*, rather than in comments. Indent your code four spaces using the `{}` toolbar button to format the code in the question.

Comment: No worries, you're new here. We don't expect you to know everything about the site right away.

Comment: So what didn't work? You described code to read the file; what do you suppose is the next logical step?

Comment: for some reason it still printed the whole file, and all the lines

Comment: Thanks for giving me -4 reputation guys. I am new to all this and dont really know how to use it. cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skip first couple of lines while reading lines in Python file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578580/skip-first-couple-of-lines-while-reading-lines-in-python-file)

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to read in the entire file upfront, you could simply iterate until you find the line number:

```
with open('packages.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if i == num:
            break
print line
```

Or you could use `itertools.islice()` to slice out the desired line (this is slightly hacky)

```
with open('packages.txt') as f:
    for line in itertools.islice(f, num+1, num+2):
        print line
```

Answer (score 4):

If the file is big, using readlines is probably not a great idea, it might be better to read them one by one until you get there.

```
line_number = int(raw_input('Enter the line number: '))
with open('packages.txt') as f:
    i = 1
    for line in f:
        if i == line_number:
            break
        i += 1
    # line now holds the line 
    # (or is empty if the file is smaller than that number)
    print line
```

(Updated to fix the mistake in the code)

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But for some reason if i enter 3 for example it will print from line 1-3?

Comment: @spinlok, s/i==1/i=1/? what do you mean?

Comment: @VincenTTTTTTTTTTTT marga initialized `i` using `i==1`,which is wrong. it should be `i=1`

Answer (score 0):

How to refer to a specific line of a file using line number ? as in java if line number = i and file is stored in f then f(i) would do.