# How to print a table from a text file and fill empty spaces?

Tags: python

I have the following table in a txt file:

```
       |Client | Container weight | Country of Origin | Product code |
       |S4378  |     450 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
       |       |     350 Ton      | Japan             | 457841       |
       |       |     900 Ton      | Japan             | 457841       |
       |       |     589 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
       |S4978  |    1400 Ton      | Mexico            | 457841       |
       |       |     980 Ton      | Emirates          | 457841       |
       |       |     550 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
       |S4578  |     450 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
```

The table starts in Line 81.

I want  to create an output text file as follows:

```
       |Client | Container weight | Country of Origin | Product code |
       |S4378  |     450 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
       |S4378  |     350 Ton      | Japan             | 457841       |
       |S4378  |     900 Ton      | Japan             | 457841       |
       |S4378  |     589 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
       |S4978  |    1400 Ton      | Mexico            | 457841       |
       |S4978  |     980 Ton      | Emirates          | 457841       |
       |S4978  |     550 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
       |S4578  |     450 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
```

I have tried extracting lines:

```
file = open('containers.txt')
lines_to_print = [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85...]
for index, line in enumerate(file):
    if index in lines_to_print:
        print(line)
```

My question is how do I write this code, if my table has 300 rows?

Comment: `if index in range(80, 300)`? You shouldn't write out the lines anyway. And if you know that the table starts at line 80 and goes until the end, just [skip the first 80 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578580/skip-first-couple-of-lines-while-reading-lines-in-python-file) and then loop until the end. No condition needed...

Comment: or `if index >= 80:` or `if 80 <= index < 300:`

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to use a csv file, instead of this file. Is that possible for your situation? Python has a ton of libraries for parsing csv files. It's harder to parse a file when the file doesn't have a distinct character separating the different fields.

Did you export this table file from a program like SSMS? If so, they usually have support for exporting as csv instead.

Answer (score 0):

To print the lines after 80 is quite easy:

```
with open('containers.txt') as in_file:
    lines = in_files.readlines()
    if len(lines) > 80:
        for line in lines[80:]:
            print(line.strip())
```

Comment: The condition is not necessary. If there are not enough lines, `lines[80:]` will give an empty list and the loop will do nothing anyway...

Answer (score 0):

When working with csv files, you should be using the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) library.
However, if you want to do it in plain python, line by line, this is one solution.

```
with open('containers.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
        for line in f:
            if line: #skip empty lines
                data = list(filter(None, map(lambda x: x.strip(), line.split('|')))) #one-liner to split the line in its data-fields and remove empty ones
                if len(data) == 4: #if the Client is missing the len will be 3
                    client = line[:9] #save the Client field
                    out.write(line + '\n')
                else:
                    out.write(f'{client}{line[9:]}\n') #use the saved Client field to fill in the gaps
```

The output file now contains:

```
|Client | Container weight | Country of Origin | Product code |
|S4378  |     450 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
|S4378  |     350 Ton      | Japan             | 457841       |
|S4378  |     900 Ton      | Japan             | 457841       |
|S4378  |     589 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
|S4978  |    1400 Ton      | Mexico            | 457841       |
|S4978  |     980 Ton      | Emirates          | 457841       |
|S4978  |     550 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
|S4578  |     450 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
```

Comment: The file is given to me in txt files and the output has to be a new txt file. I tried pandas, did not know how to fill the empty spaces.

Comment: @Mimi updated to write a file instead of printing. If you can share the txt file, I can add the pandas' code.