# New request of how to use pandas and txt files. How to fill empty spaces and filter a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table in a txt file:

line1
line2
line3
linex

January 2022 - ABC port

```
   |Client | Container weight | Country of Origin | Product code |
   |S4378  |     450 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
   |       |     350 Ton      | Japan             | 457841       |
   |       |     900 Ton      | Japan             | 457841       |
   |       |     589 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
   |S4978  |    1400 Ton      | Mexico            | 457841       |
   |       |     980 Ton      | Emirates          | 457841       |
   |       |     550 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
   |S4578  |     450 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
```

Feb 2022- Port ABC

I want to create an output text/table file as follows:

January 2022 - ABC port (being January 2022 line 1)

```
   |Client | Container weight | Country of Origin | Product code |
   |S4378  |     450 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
   |S4378  |     350 Ton      | Japan             | 457841       |
   |S4378  |     900 Ton      | Japan             | 457841       |
   |S4378  |     589 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
   |S4978  |    1400 Ton      | Mexico            | 457841       |
   |S4978  |     980 Ton      | Emirates          | 457841       |
   |S4978  |     550 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
   |S4578  |     450 Ton      | China             | 457841       |
```

Feb 2022- Port ABC (Last line)

Furthermore the number of rows for each client can change. Then client S4378 can have 3, 90,100 rows rows but all of them need to be filled with a label.

I already tried all the suggestions in my previous questions:
[How to print a table from a text file and fill empty spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72349933/how-to-print-a-table-from-a-text-file-and-fill-empty-spaces/72350269#72350269)

Comment: Have you read the table from your text file to a pandas dataframe? If so provide your dataframe constructor with `df.to_dict()`

Comment: Like not_speshal has already requested, provide us with your dataframe constructor.