# finding average of a specific window

Tags: python

I've been told that my code is correct but I keep getting

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Value'"

I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

[image]

What can I do to turn data from a CSV file into a float?

**Code:**

```
filename = input("Temperature anomaly filename:")
list_temp = []
row = 0
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        year, temp  = line.split(",")
        if row == 0:
            list_temp.append(float(temp))
        else:
            list_temp.append(float(temp))
        row = row + 1
k = int(input("Enter window size:"))
for index in range(k, len(list_temp)-k):
    year = 1880 + index
    avg = sum(list_temp[index-k:index+k+1]) / (2*k+1)
    print("{}, {:.4f}".format(year, avg))
```

**CSV data**

```
Year,Value
1880,-1.56
1881,-0.08
1882,-0.3
...
2016,0.48
2017,2.63
2018,0.18
```

> Input: 20

Comment: Please post your code as text. What is the input?

Answer (score 3):

You need to skip the header row. As the error message says, the string "Value" is not a number; it's apparently the title of the temperature column in your csv file (the fact that it's a "ValueError" is just a coincidence). Replace line 12 with `continue`. Also, you might rather use the `csv` module for this (read [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/load-csv-data-into-list-and-dictionary-using-python/)).
Try this:

```py
with open(filename) as file:
    for row, line in enumerate(file):
        if row == 0:
            continue
        line = line.strip("\n")
        year, temp  = line.split(",")
        list_temp.append(float(temp))
```

**Edit**: See solution from @imxitiz it's a bit cleaner

Comment: I put in line.strip, that should've skipped the first line, no?

Comment: that removes the newline character (`\n`) at the end of each line.

Comment: oh man how could i remove that first line?

Comment: it's handled in `if row == 0: ...` just use `continue` to skip that first iteration (read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_continue.asp) for more info)

Comment: I added that in, however it is still saying the value cannot be turned into float

Comment: to be clear, I mean you need to *replace* `list_temp.append(float(temp))` (only the one after `if row == 0:`) with `continue`. I tried it with your example input and didn't get that error. If you do get that error, that means there's a non-numeric temperature value in your csv, or a missing comma, or something

Comment: @Noah Actually, doing `continue` on line 12(Checking if, row==0 is True) would create a flaw, because `row = row + 1` this line is never executed. So, value of `row` will not be change for whole iteration!!! Hence, value of `row` would always be "0" and other condition of `row==0` is never executed.

Comment: yep good catch, then do `row = row + 1`, then `continue`

Comment: thank you guys so much! now I'm getting no output though haha my expected output is        1900,-0.4171        
I think its my "if" loop that's messing it up

Comment: @Fora Try replacing your for loop with the updated example I added to my answer, using `enumerate` to keep the row count. I did test it

Comment: thank you!if I could like I would!

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because of those header row of CSV file as @Noah points out. Here's other solution to solve this problem:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    next(file)
    for line in file:
        year, temp  = line.split(",")
        list_temp.append(float(temp))
```

Skipping the first line by doing [`next(file)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) would solve that problem. Which is considered [better for large file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9578638/12446721).
solve all these problem.

Also, `float()` function automatically removes any leading or trailing white space characters (such as spaces, tabs, and newlines) before attempting the conversion. So, no need to do, `strip()`. [float() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float)

Comment: thank you so muuch! if I could like I would!!