# Pythonic solution to drop N values from an iterator

Tags: python, iterator

Is there a pythonic solution to drop `n` values from an iterator? You can do this by just discarding `n` values as follows:

```
def _drop(it, n):
    for _ in xrange(n):
        it.next()
```

But this is IMO not as elegant as Python code should be. Is there a better approach I am missing here?

Comment: @jamylak Not with Python < 2.6 ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the "consume" recipe

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes

```
def consume(iterator, n):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```

If you don't need the special behaviour when `n` is `None`,
you can just use

```
next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```

Comment: `# Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.` ? What does this mean?

Comment: @Burhan: A number of functions/types in CPython are implemented in C code instead of Python. Those are usually faster than the Python equivalents.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid They were written in C Code so they will run at the fastest speed possible. Python code is usually slower.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, CPython is written in C, using the itertools like this avoids running bytes codes. I would expect it to run 10-100x faster than a Python loop

Comment: Thanks all. `C speed`, gotta use that one somewhere.

Comment: But the downside is that the said `deque` keeps all data until iteration is over. That might not be wanted...

Comment: @glglgl - deque gets the `maxlen=0` parameter, which prevents it from keeping all data.

Comment: Oh, very nice. This is actually a remarkable performance improvement, never thought that. I really have to look at the recipe section more often :)

Comment: Oups, ok, didn't see that. Indeed, an interesting solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can create an iterative slice that starts at element `n`:

```
import itertools
def drop(it, n):
    return itertools.islice(it, n, None)
```

Comment: Although clever, this doesn't actually drop anything until/*unless* the sequence is iterated over.

Comment: True, depends on what he needs. When it's actually dropped might not matter to him.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this with fancy use of `itertools.dropwhile`, but I would hesitate to call it in any way elegant:

```
def makepred(n):
   def pred(x):
      pred.count += 1
      return pred.count < n
   pred.count = 0
   return pred

itertools.dropwhile(it, makepred(5))
```

I really don't recommend this, though - relying on the side effects of a predicate function is very much on the odd side.