# how to extract a certain number of lines from somewhere within a file

Tags: python

I have an input file that looks something like this:

```
#nP 4
#mP 0.0262
#mH     10
#HP various info:
14  H   0.026
19  P   0.054
20  H   0.012
512 H   0.005
#xP
#kP
99
89
90
```

I want to extract 4 lines (because np = 4 in the first line) starting from line 5, so the output would be like this:

```
14  H   0.026
19  P   0.054
20  H   0.012
512 H   0.005
```

I have tried this:

```
import sys

head = sys.stdin.readline()
head = head.strip()
head = head.split('\t')
cntHetPos = int(head[1])
if "#HP" in sys.stdin.readlines():
  lines = sys.stdin.readlines()[0:cntHetPos]
  print lines
```

but it doesnt print out the lines, nor gives an error message. I based this on a previous answer I found here: [Read file from line 2 or skip header row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796764/read-file-from-line-2-or-skip-header-row)
Ideas?

Comment: This might be able to help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readlines()` returns a list of all lines the first time you call it, but the second time, it's empty because all lines have already been read and consumed. Store them in a variable:

```
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

Put that at the top because you might as well use it to read your `head` variable from:

```
head = lines[0]
```

The other problem is that you need to loop over all lines to find the `#HP` token, and you need to keep track of the line number so you can slice the list correctly:

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
  if "#HP" in line:
    lines = lines[i+1 : i+1+cntHetPos]
```

Finally, if you want to print the lines rather than the formatted list, you need to join them (note that the end-of-line character is already in there):

```
    print ''.join(lines),
```

And, for good measure, we can stop as soon as we've found the right line, so we `break` right after the `print`.

To sum up:

```
import sys

lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
head = lines[0]
head = head.strip()
head = head.split('\t')
cntHetPos = int(head[1])
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
  if "#HP" in line:
    lines = lines[i+1 : i+1+cntHetPos]
    print ''.join(lines),
    break
```

Comment: I like your answer, so +1 :P

Comment: I tried but it didn´t work... do I not need to collect the lines I want to print out outside the loop?

Comment: Updated with the full, tested, program.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty ugly matching pattern, but it might fit your needs;

```
/#nP.*?#HP.*?$.*?(\d+ +\w +[\d\.]+).*?(\d+ +\w +[\d\.]+).*?(\d+ +\w +[\d\.]+).*?(\d+ +\w +[\d\.]+)/gsm
```

It will group your results of the 4 lines you want to grab and put them into groups. You could even subgroup the results so you instantly get the `14  H   0.026` separately. Something like;

```
(\d+) +(\w) +([\d\.]+)
```

**Example**

```
import re

string = '''#nP 4
#mP 0.0262
#mH     10
#HP various info:
14  H   0.026
19  P   0.054
20  H   0.012
512 H   0.005'''

result = re.findall('#nP.*?#HP.*?$.*?(\d+ +\w +[\d\.]+).*?(\d+ +\w +[\d\.]+).*?(\d+ +\w +[\d\.]+).*?(\d+ +\w +[\d\.]+)', string, re.S | re.M)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[('14  H   0.026', '19  P   0.054', '20  H   0.012', '512 H   0.005')]
```

Comment: _Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems._ —jzw

Comment: What's the problem with some of you people on StackOverflow. Geez.. Pessimism much?

Comment: Some tongue-in-cheek intended. Sorry :) But I still don't think a regex is the right way of solving this. (Also, it doesn't solve the problem as presented, because the value 4 is not static; it's read from the file.)

Comment: It makes me think alot of the *why is jQuery needed for every JavaScript problem* spot-links people put in comments. I'll leave it to the OP to decide if it's useful. I'm not posting answers on SO to hog reputation. Just hope it can help the OP :) If we would live in a land of rainbows and unicorns, we probably would've never needed computers ;)

Comment: Yep, always good to have multiple different solutions to choose from!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('yourfile') as fin:
    count = int(next(fin).split()[1])
    non_comments = (line for line in fin if not line.startswith('#'))
    print list(islice(non_comments, None, count))
    # ['14  H   0.026\n', '19  P   0.054\n', '20  H   0.012\n', '512 H   0.005\n']
```

Comment: This does not work since there are other lines in the file that do not start with #. I only want to extract the nP number of lines (a number always given in the first line after nP in the files) after the line that starts with 'HP'.

Answer (score 0):

The [linecache module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html) is tailored for efficient line reading from files:

> The [linecache module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html) allows one to get any line from any file, while
>   attempting to optimize internally, using a cache, the common case
>   where many lines are read from a single file. This is used by the
>   traceback module to retrieve source lines for inclusion in the
>   formatted traceback.

Assuming the text file is called `blah`, and that the file data starts at the fifth line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python   

import linecache

starting_line_number = 5   
number_of_lines      = int(linecache.getline('blah',1).split()[1])
for line_num in range(starting_line_number, starting_line_number+number_of_lines):
    print linecache.getline('blah',line_num),
```