# Reading the remaining lines of a file after searching for a word in the file

Tags: python

I'm trying to read the rest of a file after finding a word.

I'm trying to write a program that searches for a word in a file and then, when the word was found, it needs to do something with the remaining lines that are below / after the word.

Here's what I have so far but it's not working. Please assist. thanks.

```
def readFile():
    with open(“file.txt”, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            if “Hello” in line:
                break
        nextline = file.readlines()
        for line in nextline 
            print(line)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796764/read-file-from-line-2-or-skip-header-row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix iteration (which basically calls the `file.next` method in the loop) and `readlines`.

To quote a great man (and [`file.next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) documentation):

> In order to make a for loop the most efficient way of looping over the
>   lines of a file (a very common operation), the next() method uses a
>   hidden read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead
>   buffer, combining next() with other file methods (like readline())
>   does not work right

You can do fine with using just iteration:

```
def readFile():
    with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            if "Hello" in line:
                break
        for line in file:
            # do something with the line
```