# Python - Skip header row with csv.reader

Tags: python

I tried this proposed solution on a large (7000 line) csv file):
[Read File From Line 2 or Skip Header Row`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796764/read-file-from-line-2-or-skip-header-row?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The following code worked but only if I manually remove the header:

```
RatedTracksFile = open('pyall_rated.csv')
RatedTracksReader = csv.reader(RatedTracksFile)
data_list = list(csv.reader(RatedTracksFile))
eligible1 = open('py_all1.csv', 'a') # open py_all1.csv in append mode
for i in range(len(data_list)):
    trackrating = int(data_list[i][12])
    ...
```

I tried different ways of adding this suggested code:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
```

I am new to python and cannot figure out how to add that in. I keep getting the same value type error since it still reads row 1,col 12 (which is a string from the header) and not the integer found on row 2, col 12:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'GroupDesc'
```

SOLVED: Based on Sphinx' comment below (thanks!).

Comment: loop from second one. like: for i in range(1, len(data_list)):

Answer (score 36):

```
import csv

with open("1800.csv", "rb") as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   next(reader, None)
   for data in reader:
      print(data)
```

This is working for me, try this.

Answer (score 30):

If your header contains your column names, the nicest solution is to use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...         print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
...
Baked Beans
Lovely Spam
Wonderful Spam
```