# how to convert from string to float in python?

Tags: python, string, floating-point, type-conversion

I am trying to convert text from a csv file to a floating point number. But i keep getting the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: year. I am getting the same error when trying to convert to int. The number that is imported is 2018.0

```
 import csv
 with open('test_csv.csv', 'rb') as data_file:
      data = csv.reader(data_file, delimiter=',')
      for i in data:
         year  = float(i[0])
```

Comment: Can you share the first few lines of the CSV? So that this is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a string to a float or int in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int-in-python)

Comment: @EvanEdwards May not be the duplicate as OP knows how to parse

Comment: There is likely some hidden character or something, can you print `repr(i)` and make sure it is just `2018.0`

Comment: Are you sure that the index you point to is ALWAYS in the format you expect it to be? Please provide the format of the CSV file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message you're getting, your issue is probably with the first line of your CSV. You haven't actually shared the contents of the file, but if I had to guess, it looks like this:

```
year,  some_value,    some_value,    ...
2018,  ...       ,    ...       ,    ...
2017,  ...       ,    ...       ,    ...
```

Your code is getting tripped up with the `year` that's on the first line of your CSV. The solution, then, is probably to skip that first line, or [use a `DictReader` instead of a `reader`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716446/python-skip-header-row-with-csv-reader).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 import csv
 with open('test_csv.csv', 'rb') as data_file:
      data = csv.reader(data_file, delimiter=',')
      for i in data:
         try:
             year  = float(i[0])
         except ValueError as e:
             print("Couldn't convert the following line {0}".format(i))
```

You probably have either a last empty line, (which creates a one empty cell array and cannot be converted) or a wrong row in your file.