# Reading .csv file with Python and DictReader missing columns

Tags: python, csv

I have the following `.csv` file I'm trying to read as a whole:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
#INFO            |           |        |       |        |      |
---------------------------------------------------------------
#Study name      | g1        |        |       |        |      |
---------------------------------------------------------------
#Respondent Name | name      |        |       |        |      |
---------------------------------------------------------------
#Respondent Age  | 20        |        |       |        |      |
---------------------------------------------------------------
#DATA            |           |        |       |        |      |
---------------------------------------------------------------
Row              | Timestamp | Source | Event | Sample | Anger|
---------------------------------------------------------------
1                | 133       | Face   | 1     | 3      | 0.44 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
2                | 240       | Face   | 1     | 4      | 0.20 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
3                | 12        | Face   | 1     | 5      | 0.13 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
4                | 133       | Face   | 1     | 6      | 0.75 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
5                | 87        | Face   | 1     | 7      | 0.25 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

[Image of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7KpT.png)

This is the code I am using to open, read the file, and print to the terminal:

```py
import csv

def read_csv():
    with open("in/2.csv", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        print(list(reader))
read_csv()
```

The output I am getting includes only the first two columns of my `.csv`:

```
[{'#INFO': '#Study name', '': ''}, {'#INFO': '#Respondent Name', '': ''}, {'#INFO': '#Respondent Age', '': ''}, {'#INFO': '#DATA', '': ''}, {'#INFO': 'Row', '': 'Anger'}, {'#INFO': '1', '': '4.40E-01'}, {'#INFO': '2', '': '2.00E-01'}, {'#INFO': '3', '': '1.30E-01'}, {'#INFO': '4', '': '7.50E-01'}, {'#INFO': '5', '': '2.50E-01'}]
```

Why are the other columns missing from my output? I want the other columns starting from `Row` to be included as well. Any direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The reader expects a file where the first row contains column names and following rows contain data entries.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I see. Thanks for letting me know. What would be a good approach to ignore the first `n` rows? Also, feel free to add your comment as an answer, and I'll gladly mark it as resolved.

Comment: There are many questions and answers on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716446/python-skip-header-row-with-csv-reader , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349333/how-to-ignore-the-first-line-of-data-when-processing-csv-data

Comment: @XaC, You're right. Thank you for the links :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DictReader` expects a file where the first row contains column names (each name different from each other) and following rows contain data entries. If multiple column names are just empty strings, the value in the last column is assigned to key `''` in the returned dictionary.

To skip the first five lines instead, you can write:

```
import csv

def read_csv():
    with open("in/2.csv", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
        for _ in range(5):
            next(f)

        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        print(list(reader))
read_csv()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
for _ in zip(f, range(5)): 
    pass
```

before initializing `DictReader`. This should skip the first 5 lines.

```
import csv

def read_csv():
    with open("in/2.csv", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
        for _ in zip(f, range(5)): 
            pass
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        print(list(reader))
read_csv()
```