# How can i get all the lines after the first in a file python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i would like to know how i could get all lines after the first in a python file

I've tried with this:

```
fr = open("numeri.txt", "r")

count = 0
while True:
    line = fr.readline(count)
    if line == "":
        break
    count += 1
    print(line)
fr.close()
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Use `for line in fr.readlines()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read file from line 2 or skip header row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796764/read-file-from-line-2-or-skip-header-row)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra if statement to check if `count != 0` Since on the first loop it will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understood well, but to obtain all the lines skipping the first one you can simple do

```
lines = []
with open("numeri.txt") as fobj:
   lines = fobj.readlines()[1:] 
count = len(lines)+1 if lines else 0 # If you want to maintain the same counting as in your example
```

Comment: The question is to iterate the lines after the first, not count them...

Comment: it doesn't say iterate all lines, it says get all lines after the first one

Answer (score 0):

Just read the first line without using it:

```
with open('numeri.txt') as f:
    f.readline()
    lines = f.readlines()
print(*lines, sep='')
```

To ignore the first line you can also use `next(f)` (instead of `f.readline()`).

This is also fine:

```
with open('numeri.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[1:]
print(*lines, sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
with open(file, 'r') as file:
    next(file.readline())  # skip the first line
    for count, line in enumerate(file.readlines()): # read remaining lines with count
        if not line:  # If line equals ""  this will be True
            break
        print(count, line)
  
count -= 1 # To ignore last lines count.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `l[1:]`. It returns a subset of l that consist in the elements of `l` except the first position.

```
with open("numeri.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()[1:]
for line in content:
    print(line.strip('\n')) # In order to avoid introduce double \n since print ends with a '\n'
```

**EDIT:** Based on @riccardo-bucco ' solution:

```
with open("numeri.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()[1:]
    print(*content, sep='')
```

Comment: `print(*content)` is enough, and won't add double `\n` characters ;)

Comment: It introduces a whitespace after every line.

Comment: Then use `print(*content, sep='')`

Comment: I made it explicitly for better understanding of the comment on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

To print all but the first line:

```py
with open('numeri.txt', 'r') as f:
    output = ''.join(f.readlines()[1:])
    print(output)
```

Answer (score -1):

start `count` at 1 so it skips the first line

```
...
count = 1
...
```