# how to skip header row in csv file while reading in python

Tags: python

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'temperature(F)\n'
```

i want to skip the header row while reading and im getting an error because it is reading the header.

```
arr = []    
with open('D:\\ml_learning\\data-structures-algorithms-python-master\\data_structures\\4_HashTable_2_Collisions\\Solution\\nyc_weather.csv', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        tokens = line.split(',')
        try:
            temperature = int(tokens[1])
            arr.append(temperature)
        except Exception as e:
            print('invalid temperature'+e)
```

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796764/read-file-from-line-2-or-skip-header-row>

Answer (score 0):

Try using `file.readlines()` and then slice it to skip the first line:

```
arr = []    
with open('D:\\ml_learning\\data-structures-algorithms-python-master\\data_structures\\4_HashTable_2_Collisions\\Solution\\nyc_weather.csv', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines[1:]:
        tokens = line.split(',')
        try:
            temperature = int(tokens[1])
            arr.append(temperature)
        except Exception as e:
            print('invalid temperature'+e)
```

Alternatively, have a look at the pandas package, which is specifically made for reading, writing and manipulating file data.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/pandas_csv.asp